# Há alguma restrição para no hibernate realizar consulta usando herança?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, paginação

Bom dia/tarde/noite Senhores.

A situação é o seguinte. Tenho uma consulta que realiza o cadastro de entidades filhas visando dividir o objeto. Porem em um momento futuro é exibido a lista. Estes dados não são todos contidos no objeto. São inclusive limitados por paginação. Apos feita a busca por paginação só está sendo retornado para mim o objeto filho salvo no banco. Quando eu claramente preciso do objeto pai, com os campos bem limitados como foi definido na herança.

Este problema não tem me parecido ter uma solução apropriada a nível de código(não que eu conheça) então preciso do auxilio dos senhores. É provável que já tenha encontrado problemas similares. E acredito esta ser uma forma mais elegante que escrever uma sql query para pegar só os campos que desejo.

O objeto que não quero exibir ou retornar que é mais vital é uma entidade que é atributo da classe pai. Esta entidade contem vários outros campos(não mostrados na tela de listagem) e inclusive outras entidades que é cascateado pelo hibernate.

Desde já grato.

O código é o mais simples que se pode imaginar. Apenas duas classes uma filha com todos os campos e uma pai apenas com, porem como o colega pediu vou postar códigos exemplos.

Vamos lá:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Pai{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id
    private String gene.
    //get's e Set's.
}

@Entity
public class Filho extend Pai{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id
    private String personalidade;
    //get's e Set's
}

public intervace PaiRepository extend JPARepository<Pai, Long>{
}
public intervace FilhoRepository extend JPARepository<Filho, Long>{
}
```

As Consultas são feitas usando `paiRepository.findAll(Pageable page);` sendo que paiRepository são instancias das interfaces acima.

Mais alguma duvida do problema só perguntar. Sou novo aqui e se vê pelos pontos. Mas pelo ritmo das negativa. Então só perguntar. Como pode ver o código é simples. O problema que quando faço a busca com o repository pai vem como se fosse o filho. Com todos os dados. O que é o que quero evitar. Já que consumiria dados no retorno e mostraria dados a mais do que deveria sendo uma falha de segurança.

Comment: Poste seu código.

Comment: E vc Negativa por isto? Nossa. Legal...

Comment: Qual é a estratégia de herança? `@Inheritance(strategy=`... Quando você busca o filho e faz um `filho.getGene()`, retorna null?

Comment: Não. O gene vai(Vem o valor do banco). Todos os dados pai e filho vão. O problema é este. Quero só os da dos do pai, neste momento os dados do filho não são importantes.